# How to addHandler with parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

If I try to pass parameter like:  `this._Click(i)` I get an error.

```
 BBtor = function(element) {
//some code

}   
 BBtor.prototype = {


    initialize: function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       $addHandler($get("Button"+i),'mouseup' , this._Click(i));
      }
    },
    
    _Click: function(param) {
           alert(param);
    }
}
```

The error I get:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error:
> Sys.ArgumentUndefinedException: Value
> cannot be undefined. Parameter name:
> handler

Again. if run this (without parameter), it works:

```
 $addHandler($get("Button"+i),'mouseup' , this._Click);
```

if I try this:

```
 $addHandler($get("Button"+i),'mouseup' , this._Click(i));
```

it's not working.

---

This worked for me:

```
$addHandler($get("Button"+i),'mouseup' , function(xx) { return function() { that._Click(xx) } } (i));
```

But with that I got another problem. how to remove the handler in dispose function?

```
dispose: function() {             
      for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     var that = this;
         $removeHandler($get("Button"+i),'mouseup' , function(xx) { return function() { that._Click(xx) } } (i));          

    },
```

I get error:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error:
> Sys.InvalidOperationException: Handler
> was not added through the
> Sys.UI.DomEvent.addHandler method.

Anyway, is it important to remove click events from the buttons?

Comment: There must be more code... What object is your for-loop in?

Comment: This is not even valid JavaScript. Is this what you have? If not please post a more complete example.

Comment: You still have a syntax error. You are missing a `}` after the `for` loop. Check first that your syntax is correct.

Comment: Felix Kling , syntax is ok. check my  update regarding the error.

Answer (score 2):

Okay so, `_Click` is a function, but `_Click(i)` is not -- `_Click(i)` is the value that function *returns* when you pass in `i` as a parameter. In this case, `_Click(i)` is `undefined` because `_Click` doesn't contain any `return` statements. Maybe you want something like this:

```
var that = this;
$addHandler($get("Button"+i),'mouseup' , function() {that._Click(i)});
```

Even though `i` is defined in the outer function, `initialize`, it's accessible in the inner (anonymous) function, `function() {that._Click(i)}`.

As for the `that = this` thing, that's necessary because inside the inner function, the value of `this` will change (I'm not sure what it will change to in this case, but it probably won't be what you expect). Another way you could do this is simply:

```
$addHandler($get("Button"+i),'mouseup' , function() {BBtor._Click(i)});
```

Comment: first option (the one with that) works but i always get 2.
second option:
I tried this but got: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: this worked for me:
$addHandler($get("Button"+i),'mouseup' , function(xx) { return function() { that._Click(xx) } } (i));

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](http://chrisdomino.com/Blog/Post/A-Quick-Gotcha-With-JavaScript-Function-Callbacks), hope it helps.

Seems that you have to accept two arguments as e is assumed to be there.

> var args = new Array();
>       args[0] = someVariable;
>       args[1] = someOtherVariable;
>       $addHandler(button, 'click', Function.createCallback(ButtonClicked, args));

```
function ButtonClicked(e, args)
{
 Useful code...
}
```